# How to query the main app's widget from inside of model's method

Tags: python, css, qt, model, pyqt

The code below creates `QTableView` linked to `QAbstractTableModel`.

[image]

When "Show All" `QCheckBox` is checked `QTableView` should show all seven Items: 'One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six' and 'Seven'.
But when unchecked `QTableView` should only show odd indexed Items.
To accomplish it first the state of `QCheckBox` needs to be queried from the inside of model's `data()` method. But since `self.checkBox` is declared inside of `Window` class it is not currently possible. 
Question: How to query the `self.checkBox` state from inside of model's methods?

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)      

        self.items=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item

        if role==QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.white))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if index.row()%2:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.gray))
            else:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGray))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return (QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return (QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)) 

        if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red))
            elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
                return QtCore.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green))

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return QtCore.QString('Horizont Column')

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            return QtCore.QString('Vertical Column')

        if role == QtCore.Qt.FontRole:
            return QtGui.QFont('Times', pointSize=12, weight=-1, italic=True)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.viewA=QtGui.QTableView()
        self.viewA.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch) 

        myModel=TableModel()
        self.viewA.setModel(myModel)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        self.checkBox=QtGui.QCheckBox("Show All")  
        self.checkBox.setChecked(True)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)  
        self.show()    

view=Window() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Qt related question. Is a code design problem.

You don't want your model knowing anything about your views. Imagine that in the future you replace your check box with other kind of view (combo box, radio group, etc), your will have to change your model...

You have to listen to changes in your check box, and then, based on the check box status, your controller should call yourmodel.loadAll() or yourmodel.loadOdd(). Using the right methods on your model, your 'TableView' will show the results automatically.

You should read something about MVC.

Comment: Should `self.checkBox` be connected to one of the model functions:  such as: `self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(my_model.cbChanged)`?

Comment: Please post some example on how to `loadAll()` or `loadOdd()` model's methods should be implemented (assuming `loadAll()` or `loadOdd()`  are the model methods and not `Window`'s functions)?

Comment: I've just posted the continuation of the same subject. Is the MVC code design implemented there properly?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592088/how-to-refresh-qtableview-when-it-is-driven-by-model