# How to refresh QTableView when it is driven by model

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qtableview

The code below creates `QTableView` driven by `self.myModel` (`QAbstractTableModel`).
'Show All' `self.checkBox` is linked to `self.myModel.cbChanged()` method.

[image]

Question: How to modify this code so 'QTableView' gets refreshed as soon as checkbox is checked?

The goal: when the checkbox is checked we want the odd numbered items to be displayed. And the even numbered items to be hidden. 
When the checkbox is off (unchecked) we want the even numbered items to be displayed. All the odd numbered items are hidden.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)      

        self.items=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']
        self.cb_status=True

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and self.cb_status:
            return item
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

    def cbChanged(self, arg=None):
        self.cb_status=arg  

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.viewA=QtGui.QTableView()
        self.viewA.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch) 

        self.myModel=TableModel()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.myModel)

        self.checkBox=QtGui.QCheckBox("Show All")  
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.myModel.cbChanged)
        self.checkBox.setChecked(self.myModel.cb_status)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)  
        self.show()   

view=Window() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Set empty model in one case and model with data in another case? View will be updated automatically.

Comment: Post an example please

Comment: Assigning an empty "dummy" model would PROBABLY work in the situation when checkbox is used to switch the items ON and OFF. But if let's say we want to use checkbox to switch between odd and even item numbers the empty model approach would not do the trick...

Comment: I agree I had to be more specific on what is needed to be achieved.

Comment: But back to the subject. How should we handle a situation when we want to display the odd numbered items with the checkbox is ON and the even numbered items when the checkbox is OFF (unchecked)?

Comment: This is a question someone can learn from and doesn't deserve a floating -1. +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use the `QSortFilterProxyModel` class. This way, we don't tamper with the actual source model's structure or it's data. We just map the main source to this proxy model, which the view uses to display filtered/sorted data. We can affect the data in the proxy model as we please, without the risk of tampering the source model.

Here is your source code modified to use this:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):   
        return len(self.items)
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)):
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        item=str(self.items[index.row()])

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()


class MySortFilterProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.cb_status=True

    def cbChanged(self, arg=None):
        self.cb_status=arg
        print self.cb_status
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        print_when_odd_flag = self.cb_status
        is_odd = True
        index = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
        print "My Row Data: %s" % self.sourceModel().data(index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)

        if (sourceRow + 1) % 2 == 0:
            is_odd = False

        if print_when_odd_flag:
            if is_odd:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            if not is_odd:
                return True
            else:
                return False


class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.viewA=QtGui.QTableView()
        self.viewA.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch) 

        self.myModel=TableModel()

        self.sortModel = MySortFilterProxyModel()
        self.sortModel.setSourceModel(self.myModel)

        self.viewA.setModel(self.sortModel)

        self.checkBox=QtGui.QCheckBox("Show All")  
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.sortModel.cbChanged)
        self.checkBox.setChecked(self.sortModel.cb_status)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)  
        self.show()   

view=Window() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, I have removed all connection from UI and the main source model. The main source model does not care about whether the checkbox is set or not. This keeps it decoupled. It's cleaner. The proxy model has been given this responsibility now. The `filterAcceptsRow()` does the main heavy lifting of displaying the right row based on whether the index of the row shown is odd or even based on the checkbox status.

I have added a few print statements to it, just in case you want to alter the logic based on the data and not the index.

Check out the docs on [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) and some [examples here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-customsortfiltermodel.html).

Hope this was useful.

Answer (score 2):

`QTableView` instance has `viewport` which has `update` method through that we can **update** the table content

Use the `update` method of `viewport` to **update** the content of a `tableview`

```
viewport().update()
```

try using :

```
self.viewA.viewport().update()
```